# One Sample T-Test in R Issues

Tags: r

Okay, I have a dataset to work with for an assignment in a graduate class I am taking. I don't understand what this question is asking me, exactly, and it's driving me nuts:

"Conduct a one-sample t-test in which you determine whether the mean of the difference in every TP concentration upstream minus the corresponding downstream TP concentration is equal to 0 or significantly different than 0. State your null hypothesis and test conclusion."

How do I do this in R? We never did this in class. I'm not wanting you to do my homework either, I'm so new to R and I don't know how to start doing anything in it. It makes me anxious.

Comment: Have you asked the professor for clarification?  That would be my go-to if I didn't understand my homework.

Comment: `?t.test` is the help page for t tests. There are examples at the bottom.

Comment: As @RichScriven commented, the best course of action is asking your professor. However, if you wish help here in SO, you can post a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#5963610)

Comment: I eventually worked through this on my own, but thank you for the responses. A lot of the terminology associated with R and comp. sci-related things makes my head spin. It's geting easier with time, though.